# Bottom door gasket doesn’t fit in dishwasher

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

Have 2014 Electrolux dishwasher. It is leaking from the bottom door of the dishwasher.

I researched a bit and ordered a new gasket.
But when I tried to install the new gasket, it doesn’t fit and I see loose from both sides and get slipped after closing the door.

Please see the picture.
Is it damaged. Can it fixed or it’s time to buy new one?

This was working before tenant left.

[image]

[image]

One of the of the door. Same is on other side.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what information is the top picture supposed to show?

Comment: It’s dishwasher with door complete open. I have highlighted the gap from both of end of the doors from inside of the dishwasher.

Comment: Are you certain that the replacement gasket you ordered is designed for your exact model of dishwasher? I have found, more than once, that when doing internet searches for a specific model number, I might get one or two hits for that model, then a bunch for _similar_ models. If I click the wrong link, I may end up looking at info for a similar, but different, product. That small difference _could_ be causing your perfectly fine gasket to not fit a door that it wasn't designed for.

Comment: @FreeMan, I have tried two different models , neither work. But didn’t you notice, the door’s exterior cover doesn’t flush ?

Comment: Sorry, no, can't get the images to load right now. Maybe one of the hinges is bent?

Comment: Have added one more picture

Comment: In the first pic, just to the right of the circle is a fastener. If that's a screw, there should be more like it. I'd consider removing all those screws and taking the plastic liner out to see if there's something behind it that's causing it to bulge out like that. I'm not sure what might cause that, but my though is that something may be stuck behind there. If it's simply bent, you may need to consider getting a whole new door interior panel.

Comment: Where it looks damaged (prob from its own hinge) isn't a mating surface. - Wrong gasket is the wrong gasket. - The 'pointy' edge that runs around the perimeter... *that* slips into the gasket.

Comment: I think I was able to find the problem. There is no problem I dishwasher door. I just didn’t how to install the gasket. lol. Thanks anyway.